# Using firebase cloud messaging http api subscribe to topic is slow

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase cloud messaging to push notification,when I use HTTP API to 
subscribe topic,it call very slow,last about 2s,why?it is too slow for me

this is the api I call:
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME

Comment: Hi James. Is this a general observation? It's hard statement to analyze without the details. How many tokens are you subscribing? How many network connections have you tried the request on? Do provide as much details as possible.

Comment: yes,i request many times and get the same result.i subscribe with only one token, and try this on my computer and aws ec2 but it also take slow